# Throwing errors in Angular application

Tags: angular, exception, error-handling

Are there any guidelines around when to throw errors in general and in particular in an Angular application?
The use cases I am thinking of:
1. The input fields required by a component has not been provided.
2. The parameters required by a function have not been provided (and specifically, in custom validators, a formControl has not been provided). 
These errors won't be caught as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is primarily opinion based. There are no rules that say if you should or shouldn't use exceptions. So I can't even say this answer is correct.

> Are there any guidelines around when to throw errors in general and in particular in an Angular application?

There are no guidelines.

Angular has ways of allowing you to listen for unhandled errors via the [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) class, but there are no limitations for throwing errors.

> 1. The input fields required by a component has not been provided.

The `@Input()` annotation does not have a *required* flag, but I wish it did.

Throwing an exception is up to you, but it's difficult to know if a binding is set or not. You can check the value of the property or check if NgOnChange was never called.

> 2. The parameters required by a function have not been provided (and specifically, in custom validators, a formControl has not been provided). These errors won't be caught as I understand it.

As with all unhandled errors they get forwarded to the ErrorHandler. There is little you can do in the class to actually handle the error.

If a parameter is required then throwing an error tells the programmer they did something wrong.

### Side Effects

If you throw unhandled errors during the Angular lifecycle hooks (which is most of the component methods) you risk breaking Angular. It's likely that the application will enter into an unrecoverable state.

From my experience the best practice is to throw errors inside Observables, and handle bad data as gracefully as possible everywhere else. Observables appear to be the only error safe domain inside Angular as I've never seen an unhandled error inside an Observable crash Angular.